# how to use value of a variable as a text of a button in java

Tags: java, button

```java
package test;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(420,420);
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        int x = 1;
        frame.add(new JButton());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would like to use the value of `x` as a text of the button, but I don't know how to do so. When I type `x` inside `JButton()`, the error *The constructor `JButton(int)` is undefined* appears.

Comment: If you want an anonymous JButton, try `frame.add ( new JButton (Integer.toString(x)));`.  If that works, consider whether you actually want an anonymous JButton.